# Ionic/Cordova - why would the UI freeze but javascript continue working away happily?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have discovered a new bug I am trying to fix with my Ionic app. Upon logging in to the app the screen freezes - the ion-spinner stops spinning, the progress bar plugin I use is stopped half way with the little spinner that goes with it completely frozen.

The odd thing is the javascript behind it keeps on working. The console shows everything as it should be. Except when I want to redirect to the app's home page, nothing happens. The app is visually frozen and I have to force quit it.

Obviously I need to find the culprit but it's difficult given that NO errors are being thrown.

The part that I don't understand is what would make the ion-spinner frozen (and screen frozen) but not throw an error?

Comment: which version of ionic? did you run on chrome first and check the debugger console for logs? is it happening on both device and browser?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the issue was with ui-router. There was a redirect loop happening causing the ui freeze